# Conditional Parameters

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Is there any way to use conditional parameters in cruise control .net.

I want if user select from select parameter(Dropdown) Dev then i will show two text box if test then one text box, depending upon condition.

Please give me any idea

Answer (score 0):

The best (and only as far as I am aware) way to achieve this is to build your own custom version of CCTray, the source is freely available here https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET.